# Is it possible to create an iptables code lock?

Tags: iptables

Is it possible to implement a simple code lock triggered by connecting ports with iptables? So for example a visitor need to connect ports 1001,1009,1008,1004 in this order to get access to port 80. Any other port hit out of order in the range 1000-1009 would reset the lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This strategy is known as "port-knocking" and there are numerous implementations.

See this link for a large list, pretty linux-centric:
http://portknocking.org/view/implementations

And the Wikipedia entry:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking

Here's an iptables-only version (which I personally find revolting):
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/268

Comment: ok, as it seems iptables alone can not provide this. If this holds, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Edited to include iptables-only example.

Comment: Fantastic! Will check this out.